# how to query on many to one mapping with jpa repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I browsed lots of stack over flow for my issue, though I got few answer that's not working in my application.
I am trying to query the data based on a field in the parent class which is mapped by @OnetoMany annotation.

My parent class is NodeDetails:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tb_node_details")
public class NodeDetails implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3232846606798223969L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "instance_id", nullable = false)
    private String instanceId;

    @Column(name = "host_id")
    private String hostId;

    @Column(name = "host_type")
    private String hostType;

    @Column(name = "client_name")
    private String clientName;
```

I have a child class which is NodeAdapterKindDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_node_adapter_kind_details")
public class NodeAdapterKindDetails implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6542657705062870675L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "adapter_kind", nullable = false)
    private String adapterKind;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id", nullable = false)
    private NodeDetails nodeDetails;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "adapterKindDetails")
    private Set<NodeAdapterInstanceDetails> adapterInstanceDetails = new HashSet<>();
```

And its child class is NodeAdapterInstanceDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_node_adapter_instance_details")
public class NodeAdapterInstanceDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "adapter_instance")
    private String adapterInstance;

    @Column(name = "active_status", columnDefinition = "varchar(20) default 'not active'")
    private String activeStatus;

    // TODO: change the timestamp from string to date... Check what is going
    // wrong in the commented setTimeStamp method
    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private String timeStamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "adapter_kind_id", nullable = false)
    private NodeAdapterKindDetails adapterKindDetails;
```

The DAO for the nodeAdapterInstance  class:

```
    @Repository(value="nodeAdapterInstanceDao")
    public interface NodeAdapterInstanceDao extends JpaRepository<NodeAdapterInstanceDetails, Long> {

        @Query("select distinct n.adapterInstance from NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n where n.adapterKindDetails.nodeDetails.clientName = :client_name")
        public List<String> getDistinctAdapterInstanceByClientName(@Param("client_name") String clientName);

        @Query("select n from NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n where n.adapterInstance = :adapter_instance and n.adapterKindDetails.nodeDetails.clientName = :client_name")
        public NodeAdapterInstanceDetails getLatestAdapterInstanceByAdapterInstanceAndClientName(@Param("adapter_instance") String adapterInstance, @Param("client_name") String clientName);

}
```

But When I try to run the spring boot, at application startup I get:

**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'adapterKindParserServiceImpl':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'nodeAdapterInstanceDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'nodeAdapterInstanceDao': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property clientName found for type NodeAdapterInstanceDetails!

**

Have I done anything wrong with the query, how could I resolve this error.
Can we use JPA repository, @query like this:

```
@Query("select n from NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n where n.adapterInstance = :adapter_instance and n.adapterKindDetails.nodeDetails.clientName = :client_name")
```

Since I don't have the client Info in the Node Adapter Instance Class I need to take it from the parent most in my hierarchy which is Node Details class.

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class AdapterKindParserServiceImpl implements NodeAdapterKindDetailsParserService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="nodeAdapterInstanceDao")
    private NodeAdapterInstanceDao nodeAdapterInstanceDao;
    private List<String> getDistinctAdapterInstances(String clientName) {
        return nodeAdapterInstanceDao.findDistinctAdapterInstanceByClientName(clientName);
    }
}
```

my complete exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'adapterKindParserServiceImpl':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'nodeAdapterInstanceDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'nodeAdapterInstanceDao': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property clientName found for type NodeAdapterInstanceDetails!    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.vmware.supernova.TopolizerApp.main(TopolizerApp.java:18)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'nodeAdapterInstanceDao': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property clientName found for type NodeAdapterInstanceDetails!    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     ... 19 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property clientName found for type NodeAdapterInstanceDetails!    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:247)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:378)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:89)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     ... 29 common
>   frames omitted

Kindly say how to resolve this exception. And if possible say what could be a better way to use the queries for @OnetoOne, @OnetoMany and @ManytoMany.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Correct your query like this:

```
select distinct 
    n.adapterInstance 
from 
    NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n 
    join n.adapterKindDetails ad
    join ad.nodeDetails nd
where 
    nd.clientName = :client_name

select 
    n 
from 
    NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n 
    join n.adapterKindDetails ad
    join ad.nodeDetails nd
where 
    n.adapterInstance = :adapter_instance and 
    nd.clientName = :client_name
```

To get ability to use the linked entity filed you first have to 'join' this entity.

More info: [JPQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_Joins)

Comment: @Query("select n from NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n join n.adapterKindDetails a join a.nodeDetails d where n.adapterInstance = :adapter_instance and d.clientName = :client_name") 

I am still getting the same exception

Comment: removing the adapter join from the above @query, I wrote this: 
@Query("select n from NodeAdapterInstanceDetails n join n.nodeDetails d where n.adapterInstance = :adapter_instance and d.clientName = :client_name")
I am still same the same issue

Comment: @Niteshkumar you shouldn't remove the adapter 'join' - your entities link as follow: InstanceDetails -> KindDetails -> NodeDetails, the `clientName` field is in `NodeDetails`. So to reach this field you have to use two joins.

Comment: @Niteshkumar Exception said `No property clientName found for type NodeAdapterInstanceDetails` - so check your query. In my queries `clientName` is in the `NodeDetails`..

Comment: Ya as you said I have used the query join for adapterkind and as well as the nodedetail, the query is given in the first comment. And if we check the NodeDetails class that I have posted in question that has clientName property as well.
Hence, I am not able to figure our why the Exception no property clientName found for type NodeAdapterInstanceDetails is show, even after doing the join from adapterInstance-> adapterKind -> nodeDetails

Comment: @Niteshkumar try to clean your project then build

Comment: Ya I did clean and build, Still facing the same issue